# NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_subscribe.firstname

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to retrieve data from a form using the Post method and store it in the database. However, when I click on the submit button,I keep on getting the following error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_subscribe.firstname
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname=request.POST.get('firstname')
        secondname=request.POST.get('secondname')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        phonenumber=request.POST.get('phonenumber')
        en= Subscribe(firstname=firstname, secondname=secondname, email = email, phonenumber = phonenumber)
        en.save()

        return redirect('/')
        
    return render(request, 'subscribe.html')
```

My models.py:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True)
    secondname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block subscribe %}
<div class="card mx-5">
    <h1 class="mx-5 mt-3"> Subscribe</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="subscribe">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3 mx-5">
            <label for="firstname" class="form-label ">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="firstname" placeholder="firstname">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 mx-5">
            <label for="secondname" class="form-label">Second Name (Optional)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="secondname" placeholder="secondname">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 mx-5">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email" placeholder="example@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 mx-5">
            <label for="phonenumber" class="form-label">Phonenumber</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="phonenumber" placeholder="0712345678">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 mx-5">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-primary"> Subscribe</button>
        </div>     
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And my url patterns:

```
urlpatterns= [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
     
    path('subscribe', views.subscribe, name ='subscribe'),
    path('allposts', views.allposts, name='allposts'),
    path('political', views.political, name='political'),
    path('religion', views.religion, name='religion'),
    path('trending', views.trending, name='treniding'),
   
    path('<str:pk>', views.post, name='post'),
 
   
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a [**`name="…"`** attribute <sup>[mdn]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#name) to the `<input>` elements, so:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="firstname" placeholder="firstname">
…
<input type="text" name="secondname" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="secondname" placeholder="secondname">
…
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email" placeholder="example@example.com">
…
<input type="number" name="phonenumber" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="phonenumber" placeholder="0712345678">
```